# Ajax post doesnt call succes after got the response

Tags: posts, jquery, ajax, javascript

done or success function is not working, it is always going in error,  but I will always get response.
**ajax call**

```
$('#DownloadAlbum').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get('AjaxURL')
        .done(function (result) {
            if(result.files.length>0) {
               /* $.post('AjaxURL',
                    JSON.stringify(result)).always(function(data, status){
                        console.log("data is:", data, "status is:", status);
                    })*/
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "AjaxURL",
                    data: JSON.stringify(result),
                    success: function (data) {
                      alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function( req, status, err ) {
                        console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err );
                    }
                })
            }else {
                console.log("inside else");
            }
        });
})
```

**Response**

```
{"location":"URl","error":null}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this situation?

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to send a request to literally `AjaxURL` as the URL.

Comment: No, There is something URL to get response, I have written dummy text.

Comment: Can you put that in then? Swap the domain out for example.com if needs be. You should also add your code from the PHP site. Also have you considered a REST API endpoint? Much easier to do, much harder to mess up